# Script to take pid, give cmd name, network connections, process tree, parent/grandparent/child

Tags: process

Okay, so

I need to write a script which will take pid as an argument and give me the command name, the various network connections associated the process, and it will also give that information for up to three ancestor processes, and up to three generations of descendants.

I don't want the answer to this, but I do want some guidance on how best I can set myself on the right course to finishing this.

This is what I have started out with:

```
#!/bin/bash
#get pid from user
PID=$1
#echo pid and find a way to describe process to user
echo $PID #whatever it is = #whatever the command name is
#network portion
sudo netstat -p grep $PID
#this return information related to the process itself
ps -ef f|egrep "(UID|$PID)"
```

The last line of code will at least return something somewhat valuable to me: I can get some information related to the process, a tree-like hierarchy, ect ect.

I don't posses a lot of technical knowledge so I understand if this code simply looks horrible/unusable for this assignment. If I need to start from scratch and come up with different ideas I will. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the PID of the parent process with this:

```
PID=1234
ps -o ppid --no-headers -p "$PID"
```

or with

```
awk '/^PPid:/ { print $2 }' /proc/$PID/status
```

You get it into a variable with

```
PPID="$(awk '/^PPid:/ { print $2 }' /proc/$PID/status)"
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you can explain to me what this line of code is doing so that I may understand this a little better?

Comment: `ps` is used to print the process list. You can format the output. `ps` takes its data from the `/proc` filesystem. You get get the data from there directly, too.

Comment: Thanks Hauke; I'll keep adding on to it and see if I can do something awesome with this.